# What is the proper community for GPL licence question?

Tags: support, legal, licensing, superuser

I would like to ask a question about a licence (GNU GPL) but, I am not sure which is the right community. I have already read many sources, including the official one and also the most frequent asked questions section. However, since this is a delicate matter and I would not want to ruin things, I want to make sure that I understood correctly. Also, not being a native english speaker causes me trouble when it comes to specific topics - like licences for example.
Someone suggested me Superuser, but It did not seem like the right place.